# Finding the surface area of the spheroid $\frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{y^2}{3} + \frac{z^2}{4} = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I'm asked to evaluate this:

> What is the surface area of the surface defined by $\frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{y^2}{3} + \frac{z^2}{4} = 1$?

I first parameterized it with spherical coordinates and then I took the cross product and then the magnitude of the cross product of $r(\phi) \times r(\theta)$.
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
x &= \sqrt{3} \cos\theta \sin\phi, \\
y &= \sqrt{3} \sin\theta \sin\phi, \\
z &= 2\cos\phi;
\end{aligned}\right\}\qquad
0 < \theta < 2\pi,\quad
0 < \phi < \pi.
\end{equation}
I took the partials with respect to $\phi$ and $\theta$ and arrived at
\begin{align*}
r(\theta) &= (-\sqrt{3} \sin\theta \sin\phi, \sqrt{3} \cos\theta \sin\phi, 0), \\
r(\phi) &= (\sqrt{3} \cos\theta \cos\phi, \sqrt{3} \sin\theta \cos\phi, -2 \sin\phi).
\end{align*}

Once I found the partials, I took the cross product between them and then took its magnitude to get
$$
\int \sin\phi \sqrt{12\sin^2\phi + 9\cos^2\phi}\, d\phi.
$$

Now, I've tried plenty of trig things but I just can't solve this integral. Can someone help me?

Comment: Since the arclength of a noncircular ellipse has no simple formula it's likely also not simple to get the value of the surface area of your nonspherical ellipsoid. The integral seems like it might be a transform of an elliptical integral...

Comment: The soultion is non elementary. You have been asked to compute the surface of an ellipsoid, and that is given in terms of the first and second incomplete elliptic integrals.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid for the general case. Interesting are he approximate formulas for the general case and the exact formulas for the oblate and prolate cases.

Comment: You changed the equation (which is no more readable) but you don't tell how you arrived to this integral which by the way results in a complex result. Please, fix the equation and explain.

Comment: Hi, I edited it. Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: As augurar notes, you've got a _spheroid_, not a general ellipsoid. And sure enough, your integral is elementary, thanks to the extra $\sin \phi$ outside the radical. :) Write $\sin^{2} \phi = 1 - \cos^{2} \phi$, use $u = \cos \phi$ to get $\int\sqrt{12 - 3u^{2}}\, du$, then put $u = 2\sin x$ (or do this all in one step).

Comment: Hi, I understand how to get to that integral, but could you further explain the u=2sinx? If you set u = cos (phi) wouldn't du = -sin(phi) d(phi) so that leaves you with -sqrt(12-3u^2)du?

Comment: @Alex: The trig substitution $u = 2\sin x$ gives $du = 2\cos x\, dx$, so$$\int \sqrt{12 - 3u^{2}}\, du = \int \sqrt{12 - 12\sin^{2} x}\ \cdot 2\cos x\, dx = 4\sqrt{3} \int \cos^{2} x\, dx.$$

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you so much. But I have some questions: when you set u=cos(phi) isnt du = - sin (phi) so it would be the negative of your integral? I also understand how to integrate cos^2(x) by breaking it up into 1/2 + 1/2cos2x....however..I am having difficulty with the bounds. I plugged in phi into the original u sub to get u = -1 and u = 1. Then I plugged in the u bounds into the second u substitution to get x = 7pi/6 and x = pi/6..I plugged in these bounds and it is not yielding the correct answer. What went wrong?

Comment: Ah... I finally found my problem. It's been so long since so long I've forgotten the restrictions for inverse sine...THANK YOU SO MUCH! I couldn't have done this without all of you guys. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Alex: Just saw your comments. Glad to hear it worked out. :) If you're willing/able to type up the details, it's perfectly appropriate to answer your own question.

Comment: @user86418 You should put your comments in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that two of the axes of the ellipsoid are the same, and the third is longer.  Thus it is actually a [prolate spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid).  The formula for the surface area of the prolate spheroid $\frac{x^2 + y^2}{a^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ is:
$$ S=2\pi a^2 + 2\pi\frac{ac}{e}\sin^{-1}e $$
where $e$ is the ellipticity $\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{c^2}}$.

This formula is derived by considering the spheroid as a [surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution) about the $z$-axis and doing the usual integration to find its area:

$$S = 2\pi \int_{-c}^{c}{r(z) \sqrt{1+(r'(z))^2}\,dz}$$

where $r(z) = a\sqrt{1-\frac{z^2}{c^2}}$ is the radius of the circular cross section at height $z$.

Source:

- [Wolfram MathWorld - Prolate Spheroid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProlateSpheroid.html)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. Could you set up the integral for deriving the formula? I'm not quite understanding what to do. Do you disregard the "z" value?

Comment: @Alex The link gives the details, although you can also do this using the integral you originally set up, per user86418's comments.